# Retrieving a value from a checkbox is in wrong encoding format

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have pdf with checkboxes. Now I want to set with pdfbox a value of a checkbox, so that it is checked. When the onValue of the checkbox contains german special chars, then it will not work otherwise it works.

I think the reason for this is, that the encoding of the checkbox value is encoded as windows-1252 and the setValue which I try to use is in UTF-8.

Here is my TestMethod with which reproduce the error

```
final String newValue = "Spülen";
PrefillDataDrawer drawer = new PrefillDataDrawer(pdf);

PDField field = getPDFieldForName(searchField);
assertNotNull(field);
PDCheckBox cb = (PDCheckBox) field;

assertEquals(newValue, cb.getOnValue());
```

The output is:

```
expected:<Sp[Ã¼]len> but was:<Sp[ü]len>
Expected :SpÃ¼len
Actual   :Spülen
```

As I learned the console of intellij uses the system encoding, in my case windows-1252, thats why you see the actual value correctly and the expected value is UTF-8 and is shown as: SpÃ¼len

To prove that I can change the above newValue to this

```
final String newValue = "Sp\u00FClen";
```

then my test passes.

So my problem is that cb.getOnValue() delivers an string in windows-1252. Is it possible to change this with pdfbox or is there another solution possible so that the string compare passes?

Comment: This does not look like a PDFBox issue but instead an issue of your development environment: The editor seems to work with UTF-8 and the compiler assumes CP1252. This at least is what your `"Sp\u00FClen"` test result suggests.

Comment: When I change the encoding of my class to CP1252 then it works also with the value "Spülen" but this indeed means the value which i receive from the pdf is CP1252. Is it now necessary that I switch to CP1252 in my workspace??? I would prefer to use UTF-8 in my workspace and pdfbox need to deliver the value as UTF-8?

Comment: I guess I solved it by adding this to my buidl.gradle compileJava.options.encoding = "UTF-8"
compileTestJava.options.encoding = "UTF-8" Now assertEquals works.

Comment: *I guess I solved it by adding this to my buidl.gradle compileJava.options.encoding = "UTF-8"* - that's exactly what you needed for a proper development environment. You may want to make that an answer to your question.

Comment: My testscase works now, but when deploy my web-app with the gradle tomcat plugin on a tomcat 8, the code which works in my test fails as before. Encoding of the embedded tomcat is wrong/ different?

Comment: Additional info, I dont think that tomcat is the reason. I have changed my app so that it starts from the command line, this fails also although the testcase passes. Really strange or too late :-) but i am curious whats the reason. @mkl maybe you have another idea.

Comment: If the same compiled code works out of the ide but not on the command line, then you either do something that only works that requires the sources to be present (e.g. loading something with a path 'src/main/resources') or at least the resources not to be packaged yet, or you start it somehow differently. That been said, does the `"Sp\u00FClen"` workaround work from the command line?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163063/discussion-between-al-phaba-and-mkl).

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that the compiler and the ide (intellij) used different encodings. The IDE used UTF-8 and the compiler CP1252, this could be changed by adding these two lines to my build.gradle

```
compileJava.options.encoding = "UTF-8"
compileTestJava.options.encoding = "UTF-8"
```

With that my case worked as expected.